# Getting Timeout Error in ElasticSearch RestHighLevelClient object. How to extend the time limit of 30000 ms?

Tags: rest, http, elasticsearch, timeout, resthighlevelclient

Here is the error trace :

```
java.io.IOException: listener timeout after waiting for [30000] ms
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:663)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:222)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:194)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:488)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:474)
```

Here is my java code :

```
 RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));
```

I tried using the following line of code but it didn't work :

```
client.timeout(new TimeValue(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
```

I also tried this but it didn't work either :

```
 RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http").setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(100000).build()));
```